# how to get php to execute a python file

Tags: php, python, json

i'm trying to get php to execute a python program, yet it doesn't want to execute it. the point of the python code is to get a 6-digit code from a text file, get data from a database and manipulate it, then save that data to a .txt file. this works perfectly fine when running it through IDLE, but the php code won't execute it. what's going wrong here?

the php code:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("uniprocode.txt", "w+");
    $txt = $_POST['code'];
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

    $result = exec('C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe comp.py');
    $r = json_decode($result);
    foreach($r as $row){
        echo $row ."<br>";
    }
?>
```

the python code:

```
import re
from Bio import ExPASy
from Bio import SwissProt
from pathlib import Path
import os
import json

#uniprot ascension code regex from the uniprot site:
uniprotregex = '[OPQ][0-9][A-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]|[A-NR-Z][0-9]([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]){1,2}'
#this string is {P}-{PKRHW}-[VLSWFNQ]-[ILTYWFN]-[FIY]-{PKRH}
#which i believe is a string that goes:
#"not P, not any of PKRHW, only VLSWFN or Q, only ILTYWF or N, only FI or Y, not any of PKRH"
protregex = '[^P][^P^K^R^H^W][VLSWFNQ][ILTYWFN][FIY][^P^K^R^H]'

g = open('uniprocode.txt')
y = g.readlines()
o = str(y)
t = o.strip("\'[]\'")
print(str(t))

def gogogo():
    try:
        hand = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(str(t))
    except:
        f = open("sequencefinder.txt", "w+")
        f.write("Error: This is not a uniprot code.")
    else:
        data = SwissProt.read(hand)
        seq = data.sequence
        match = re.findall(protregex, seq)
        f = open("sequencefinder.txt", "w+)
        f.write("Protein\tStart position\tEnd position\tSequence\n")
        for m in re.finditer(protregex, seq):
            f.write(t + "\t" + str(m.start() + 1) + "\t\t" + str(m.end() + 1) + "\t\t" + str(m.group(0) + "\n"))
        f.close()
    r = open("sequencefinder.txt")
    return json.dumps(r)

if __name__ == "__main":
    print gogogo()
```

Comment: Anything in the error logs?  Have you tried providing a complete path for "comp.py" ?  Also, given you're on windows, I have to wonder if PHP has permission to run python.exe under the "Program Files" directory?

Comment: This looks like a PHP config error.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php  Checkout  the notes on windows and safe_mode